# How to preserve rich text formatting in contentNote after escaping HTML characters to prevent XSS attack

Tags: apexrest, contentnote, xss

I need to insert contentNote record from apex rest api. Below is the sample code

```
ContentNote noteRecord = new ContentNote();
    noteRecord.Title   = 'Title';
    String body        = restJSONdata.get('content');
    noteRecord.Content = Blob.valueOf(body.escapeHTML4());
    insert noteRecord;
    
    ContentDocumentLink link = new ContentDocumentLink();
    link.ContentDocumentId   = noteRecord.id;
    link.LinkedEntityId      = '0015h00001brgJq';
    link.ShareType           = 'V';
    link.Visibility          = 'AllUsers';
    insert link;
```

here restJSONdata is json map received in request body and value of content in request body will have some html content like this `"content" : "<b> Some text </b>"`. Since I am using escapeHTML4() the final content that gets stored doesnt hold rich text formatting and instead of saving the text as bold, it saves it along with the html tags like this `<b>Some text </b>` . When I use the code as below, it does saves the formatting but doesnt takes care on xss attack .

```
contentNote.Content = Blob.valueOf(body);
```

Is there any way I can retain rich text format without compromising with cross site scripting?